# SAS 9.4 Stored Process Log file monitoring

Tags: logging, sas, monitoring

I am seeing that the log information from a SAS Stored Process (STP) is appended to the .log file only upon completion of the STP. I want to monitor long running STPs by tailing the STP log file. Is there a way to get SAS to write the log information immediately instead of this delayed behavior?

Example: I kick off an STP (stp_test.sas) and tail the log file. The last line see is:

```
2016-02-19T11:05:03,630 INFO  [00000004] :sassrv - [00000003] STPXUTL Execute using file path:  /SAS/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasstp/stp_test.sas
```

Only upon completion (53 seconds later) I get the following next lines including specifically the NOTES that are important to me.

```
2016-02-19T11:05:56,634 INFO  [00079501] 8:sasmi - STP: 3: Execution Complete.  Status=4
2016-02-19T11:05:56,678 INFO  [00079501] 8:sasmi - NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file /SAS/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasstp/stp_test.sas is file /SAS/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasstp/stp_test.sas.
2016-02-19T11:05:56,679 INFO  [00079501] 8:sasmi - NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
2016-02-19T11:05:56,679 INFO  [00079501] 8:sasmi -       real time           0.00 seconds
2016-02-19T11:05:56,679 INFO  [00079501] 8:sasmi -       cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the code in proc printto:

```
filename stplog temp;
proc printto log=stplog;run;
*your stp goes here;
proc printto;run;
```

Now, the log will be written to this temp file in the Stored Process Server work directory. I would still add write=immediate as Robert suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `write=immediate` option on [logparm](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002303556.htm).

We specify it as a startup parameter when we launch sas:

```
-logparm="write=immediate"
```

but you may be able to specify it at runtime too.

Comment: That did not change the behavior of the STP.